# Does making an attack with a previously cast Spiritual Weapon spell cause the Invisibility spell to end?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, invisibility, duration

Suppose a character casts the *spiritual weapon* spell one round, then casts the *invisibility* spell the following round.

Does using the bonus action from *spiritual weapon* to attack count as making an attack for the sake of ending the *invisibility* spell?

Comment: Related: "[What is the attacker for Spiritual Weapon? The caster or the weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168947)" and "[Can a hidden character make an attack with the Spiritual Weapon spell and still remain hidden?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125240)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes because you are making an attack

[*Invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility) states:

> The spell ends for a target that **attacks** or casts a spell.

and [*Spiritual Weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon) states:

> you can make a **melee spell attack** against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon.
> [...]
> As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the weapon up to 20 feet and **repeat the attack** against a creature within 5 feet of it.

Since using *Spiritual Weapon* involves making an attack it breaks *Invisibility*.

Furthermore you can look to the rule in the section "Making an Attack" (PHB, page 194):

> If there’s ever any question whether something you’re doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you’re making an attack roll, you’re making an attack.